# Passing Javascript Variable to Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, request

I have read several postings on different examples for passing a javascript variable to flask through post/get forms. I still don't understand how to do this. From my understanding, the form creates a post/get that can then be called and received by the python flask script. Can someone write up a very simple example on what this should look like?

Starting from creating a variable with any value in javascript and then making the post/get. Lastly what should the receiving end on python should look like and finally print the variable from python.

Comment: This question is too broad. Learn how to create a minimal Flask application (great guide here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) and then learn how to pass parameters to a Flask endpoint.

Comment: I find it unfortunate that this question was closed. I've used flask for simple setups before but the GET/POST stuff was still confusing to me. The provided answer below was incredibly useful. I wish I could contribute my as-simple-as-possible version for others to get started.

Answer (score 9):

How I did this was using an ajax request from the javascript which would look something like this. I think the easiest way would be using JQuery as well since it might be a bit more verbose with pure javascript.

```
// some movie data
var movies = {
    'title': movie_title,
    'release_date': movie_release_date
    }

$.ajax({
url: Flask.url_for('my_function'),
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify(movies),   // converts js value to JSON string
})
.done(function(result){     // on success get the return object from server
    console.log(result)     // do whatever with it. In this case see it in console
})
```

Flask.url requires JSGlue which basically let's you use Flask's 
url_for but with javascript. Look it up, easy install and usage. Otherwise I think you could just replace it with the url e.g '/function_url'

Then on the server side you might have something like this:

```
from flask import request, jsonify, render_template
import sys

@app.route("/function_route", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def my_function():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = {}    // empty dict to store data
        data['title'] = request.json['title']
        data['release_date'] = request.json['movie_release_date']

       // do whatever you want with the data here e.g look up in database or something
       // if you want to print to console

        print(data, file=sys.stderr)

        // then return something back to frontend on success

        // this returns back received data and you should see it in browser console
        // because of the console.log() in the script.
        return jsonify(data)
    else:
        return render_template('the_page_i_was_on.html')
```

I think the main points are to look up ajax requests in jquery, flask's request.json() and jsonify() functions.

Edit: Corrected syntax

Comment: I am in the same boat as the OP where I am struggling to figure out how to pass a variable from JS to Flask, and I understand you can't but there's work-arounds. All the work-around explanations seem confusing for me, but I mostly followed along here, but I get lost at the "return jsonify(data)" part. I'm looking to return results from a database, and I just want to get the parameters for what to query from JS.