# How can I send data from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I'm working on a project for school : webapp using python. I'm using FLASK, and by the help of render_template I was able to send data from Python then get it on the other hand (on HTML).

I executed some JavaScript that holds some variables, and what I'm looking for is to how to send these variables from this JavaScript script to Python.

Comment: Have you tried this solution?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645790/passing-javascript-variable-to-python-flask

Comment: Hi yeah i tried this one, but it gives me this error : 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.
The ajax code is not working or it sends an empty json, any idea ?