# get javascript variable value and store it to django variable and use it vice versa

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to store the javascript values in my django variables or use it in my view query

```js
//javascript values want to store in django
var js_latitude = 122.33;
var js_longitude = 12.22;

django_latitude = js_latitude
django_longitude = js_longitude
```

save this value to my Django variable and calculate or multiply the values then it will be displayed by view or use in my query . just like location variable and save to Django and calculate distance than also

Comment: What is the source of Javascript values, is it generated in DOM?

Comment: its simple static strings let for example, otherwise its string from android .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Javascript Variable to Python Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645790/passing-javascript-variable-to-python-flask)

Comment: I have solve it by passing the variables to url .